# Postfix logs nowhere to be found in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, syslog, rsyslog

I have not changed *any configuration* in any of the tools, specially not in:

- syslog
- rsyslog
- postfix
- systemd

(If any apply)

In my `/var/log` there is no `/var/log/mail.log`, `/var/log/postfix.log` or `/var/log/syslog`

What is happening here? What is the log facility used by Ubuntu 14.04.3? Where are the logfiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I see on my box:

```
ws:/# postconf syslog_facility
syslog_facility = mail
ws:/# grep '^mail' /etc/rsyslog.d/*
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:mail.*                           -/var/log/mail.log
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:mail.err                 /var/log/mail.err
ws:/# grep -v '^#' /etc/rsyslog.d/postfix.conf 
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
ws:/#
```

Do you see the same?

Edit: `/var/log` ended up not being writable for syslog, namely `drwxr-xr-x  root root` instead of `drwxrwxr-x root syslog`, so a `chown root:syslog /var/log && chmod 775 /var/log` did the trick.

Comment: Exactly the same. Still, no logfile, not even in `/var/spool/postfix/dev/log` (the directory does not even exist!)

Comment: /var/spool/postfix/dev/log should be a socket: `ws:/#ls -l /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Aug 18 08:23 /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
ws:/#`

Comment: Can you run: `logger -p mail.debug Test` And check where that ends up ?

Comment: I have tried, both with and without sudo, and there are no logs neither in /var/log nor in /var/spool/postfix/dev/log. Where do your logs end up? How can I know where the logger command is sending the logs? Is there a verbose flag? (can't see it)

Comment: And: `ls: cannot access /var/spool/postfix/dev/log: No such file or directory`

Comment: My logs end up in `/var/log/mail.log`, as specified in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`... Is your syslogd running ? `service rsyslog status` should give something like `rsyslog start/running, process 462`

Comment: `rsyslog start/running, process 588` ... something fishy is going on in my system! :(

Comment: Running `lsof -p <syslog_pid>` gives me:  `rsyslogd 462 syslog    0u  unix 0xffff8800b65aa680      0t0       9684 /dev/log`
`rsyslogd 462 syslog    1w   REG                9,2   361974   43254991 /var/log/auth.log`
`rsyslogd 462 syslog    2w   REG                9,2    32145   43253927 /var/log/syslog`
`rsyslogd 462 syslog    3u  unix 0xffff8800b65a9c00      0t0       9686 /var/spool/postfix/dev/log`
`rsyslogd 462 syslog    4r   REG                0,3        0 4026532034 /proc/kmsg`
`rsyslogd 462 syslog    5w   REG                9,2   102392   43254990 /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: In  my case: `sudo lsof -p 588 | grep -v ' /usr' | grep -v ' /lib'` -> `COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
rsyslogd 588 syslog  cwd    DIR                8,2     4096          2 /
rsyslogd 588 syslog  rtd    DIR                8,2     4096          2 /
rsyslogd 588 syslog    0u  unix 0xffff88024f526c80      0t0       1902 /dev/log
rsyslogd 588 syslog    3r   REG                0,3        0 4026532034 /proc/kmsg
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29662/discussion-between-marcolz-and-jeckyll2hide).

Comment: `/var/log` ended up not being writable for syslog, namely `drwxr-xr-x  root root` instead of `drwxrwxr-x root syslog`, so a `chown root:syslog /var/log && chmod 775 /var/log` did the trick.